# Telnet Login Incorrect - Ubuntu - Connnecting to Router

Tags: ubuntu, router, telnet

i cannot login to the router using telnet and getting login incorrect in Ubuntu 18.x what's the problem

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ezzat# telnet 192.168.1.1
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
-------------------------------
-----Welcome to ATP Cli------
-------------------------------

Login: admin
Password: 
Login incorrect. Try again.

Login: admin
Password: 
Login incorrect. Try again.

Login:
```

Comment: This error does not come from `telnet`, as you manage to open a connection with the remote router.<br>
Are you sure that you type the good password ?

Comment: You might want to see:  https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/151-Huawei-B593-Logging-into-shell-Solved!.html

Answer (score 1):

Telnet seems to be fine - just the user or password is wrong. Do your password consist of special characters? Then perhaps you have set your keyboard to the wrong language.

Comment: everything is ok and still getting error